# How to map a somewhat complex architecture with automapper and constructUsing

Tags: c#, automapper, automapper-6

I have the following situation which I cannot get mapped properly:

I receive a list of following objects from a call to the camunda api.

```
public class CamundaTask
{
    public string FormKey { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

And I would like to map it to specific tasks in my code (`ContactUpdateTask` or `OrganisationAquisitionTask`) depending on the formkey.

Following is my architecture:

```
public class BaseTask
{
    public virtual string TaskType { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int Priority { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    ...
}

public abstract class ProcessTask<TContext> : BaseTask
{
    public TContext TaskContext { get; set; }
}

public class ContactUpdateContext
{
    public Guid PersonId { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}

public class OrganisationAquisitionContext
{
    public Guid OrganisationId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ContactUpdateTask : ProcessTask<ContactUpdateContext>
{
    public override string TaskType { get => "UpdateContact"; }
}

public class OrganisationAquisitionTask : ProcessTask<OrganisationAquisitionContext>
{
    public override string TaskType { get => "OrganisationAquisition"; } 
}
```

I know how to deal with simple inheritance and automapper but the whole TContext throws me off a little.
This is what I have so far but it produces following error: "Mapper not initialized. Call Initialize with appropriate configuration."

```
CreateMap<ContactUpdateTask, ProcessTask<ContactUpdateContext>>().ReverseMap();
CreateMap<ContactValidationTask, ProcessTask<OrganisationAquisitionTask>>().ReverseMap();
CreateMap<OrganisationAquisitionTask, ProcessTask<ContactValidationTask>>().ReverseMap();

CreateMap<BaseTask, CamundaTask>()
   .ForMember(t => t.FormKey, opt => opt.MapFrom(p => p.TaskType))
   .ForMember(t => t.Assignee, opt => opt.MapFrom(p => p.Owner))
   .ForMember(t => t.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(p => p.Key))
   .ForAllOtherMembers(opt => opt.Ignore());

CreateMap<CamundaTask, ContactUpdateTask>()
    .ForMember(t => t.TaskType, opt => opt.MapFrom(p => p.FormKey))
    .ForMember(t => t.Owner, opt => opt.MapFrom(p => p.Assignee))
    .ForMember(t => t.Key, opt => opt.MapFrom(p => p.Id))
    .ForAllOtherMembers(opt => opt.Ignore());

CreateMap<CamundaTask, ContactValidationTask>()
    .ForMember(t => t.TaskType, opt => opt.MapFrom(p => p.FormKey))
    .ForMember(t => t.Owner, opt => opt.MapFrom(p => p.Assignee))
    .ForMember(t => t.Key, opt => opt.MapFrom(p => p.Id))
    .ForAllOtherMembers(opt => opt.Ignore());

CreateMap<CamundaTask, OrganisationAquisitionTask>()
    .ForMember(t => t.TaskType, opt => opt.MapFrom(p => p.FormKey))
    .ForMember(t => t.Owner, opt => opt.MapFrom(p => p.Assignee))
    .ForMember(t => t.Key, opt => opt.MapFrom(p => p.Id))
    .ForAllOtherMembers(opt => opt.Ignore());

CreateMap<CamundaTask, BaseTask>()
    .ConstructUsing((CamundaTask task) =>
    {
        switch (task.FormKey.ToLower())
        {
            case "updateorganization":
                return Mapper.Map<ContactUpdateTask>(task);
            case "contactValidation":
                return Mapper.Map<ContactValidationTask>(task);
            case "organizationacquisition":
                return Mapper.Map<OrganisationAquisitionTask>(task);       
        }

        return Mapper.Map<BaseTask>(task);
    })
   .ForMember(t => t.TaskType, opt => opt.MapFrom(p => p.FormKey))
   .ForMember(t => t.Owner, opt => opt.MapFrom(p => p.Assignee))
   .ForMember(t => t.Key, opt => opt.MapFrom(p => p.Id))
   .ForAllOtherMembers(opt => opt.Ignore());
```

I map with the following line of code:

```
var tasks = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<BaseTask>>(camundaTasks)
```

Where `camundaTasks` is of type `IEnumerable<CamundaTask>`

What is the proper way to do the mapping so that my tasks list contains objects of `ContactUpdateTask` or `OrganisationAquisitionTask` depending on the formkey of the `CamundaTask`?

Comment: What the error says ? Does it tell you anything about a particular missing map or something ?

Comment: try using
.ConstructUsing((CamundaTask task, ResolutionContext context) =>

and then rather than statically calling Mapper.Map, you can call
context.Mapper.Map

Comment: Hi Nico, if you transform your comment into an answer (and elaborate a bit on what it does :) i'll mark it as the answer)

Comment: @dbraillon The error didn't say anything about a particular missing map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what happens here is that you initialize Automapper in a non-static way (isn't clear from your original post, but I could deduct that because my comment seemed to have solved your problem), but you are using Automapper statically within the ConstructUsing method.

There's two solutions for this:

1) Use Automapper statically

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg=> cfg.CreateMap<CamundaTask, BaseTask>());
```

2) Use ResolutionContext

```
.ConstructUsing((CamundaTask task, ResolutionContext context) =>
{
    switch (task.FormKey.ToLower())
    {
        case "updateorganization":
            return context.Mapper.Map<ContactUpdateTask>(task);
        case "contactValidation":
            return context.Mapper.Map<ContactValidationTask>(task);
        case "organizationacquisition":
            return context.Mapper.Map<OrganisationAquisitionTask>(task);       
    }

    return context.Mapper.Map<BaseTask>(task);
})
```